Do I have to leave my backpack at the door at Dollar General?
Because I am a student, it is hard to go places without worrying about being accused of shoplifting. Recently, Dollar General has placed a "No Backpack" policy for students, not allowing them to bring their backpack fully inside the store. We are expected to leave our backpack unattended.
The first time was after school, and I had wanted to buy a card for my sister. The kind cashier told me to leave my backpack at the door. when I had inquired, she claimed it was "store policy". I did not want to leave my bag unattended, so I just left.
The second time, two days later, I went into the store with my parents. My mom had a big purse and my dad had a military backpack on. They did not ask them to take it off. What the hell? Are they liable for things stolen?

Is this in the United States?  Somewhere else?

@MichaelSeifert Dollar General has about 19,300 stores in the US and 111 in Mexico. So almost certainly the US.

The alternative would probably be to inspect the contents of your backpack on the way out, to make sure you didn't shoplift.

@Barmar Not that I think it particularly changes the answer, but I think the discriminated-against class is "students" and not "backpack-wearers"--the question asker's parents were non-student backpack wearers who were not asked to leave it at the door.

@Kaia Actually, it seems more like it's "young people". And presumably the justification is that they think young people are more likely to be shoplifters (this seems to be true: https://expresslegalfunding.com/shoplifting-statistics-survey/)

Yes, this is in the United States, and I don't disagree that young people are most likely to be shoplifters. So far, I have stayed clear of Dollar General, which seems like it's the best thing I can do. I am just wondering if they are liable for items stolen. I cannot find their "Store Policy" and what I am agreeing to, at least not online.

Only if you want to go in
Their store, their rules.
Also, they are not under any obligation to enforce the rules uniformly unless the non-uniform application discriminates against people of a protected class. So, enforcing it for children and not adults is age discrimination; but age discrimination in the USA is only illegal if it works against people aged over 45.
